# Android. Google Play Services. Saved Games are not working

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games

I try to implement "Saved Games" feature for my game.
When I try to save game or load it programmatically, I get exception: `Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console`

more detailed exception:

```
2022-02-19 12:58:08.719 25925-25925/com.ilyin.secret_crate2 E/LoadProcess: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2445)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2421)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2404)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2346)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.games.zzb.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-games@@21.0.0:22)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.zzaf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-games@@21.0.0:254)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.zzf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-games@@21.0.0:460)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.games.zzdn.accept(com.google.android.gms:play-services-games@@21.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.games.zzaf.accept(com.google.android.gms:play-services-games@@21.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacv.doExecute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zag.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaJ(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaL(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zap(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:64)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

There is what I already done to make Saved Games work:

1. Play Services in Google Play Console are configured and Saved Games are enabled. Configuration is published (I know about 24 hours delay. I published it more than 2 weeks ago).
2. I added my email to list of testers.
3. In Google Cloud Platform created OAuth clients.
4. In Google Cloud Platform enabled `Google Play Game Services API` and `Google Drive API`
5. In `AndroidManifest.xml` I added app id.
6. My signing-in options programmatically looks like:

```
val GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_OPTIONS_DEFAULT: GoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
    .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_SNAPSHOTS)
    .build()
```

I done all these steps. Sign-in, leaderboard and achievements are works well. But Saved Games still not working. What may be wrong?

Comment: The error message clearly says that Saved Game is not enabled, not that you failed to connect to your service. Could it be possible that you had incorrect Game Services ID entered in your project?

Comment: All settings was correct. Problem was solved automatically in 3 weeks. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Sorry to have brought up an old thread.